# replace MCrypt Rijndael 128 (ECB, no IV) with cryptian code

Tags: node.js, mcrypt

I am trying to port a code using MCrypt (which is now deprecated):

```
const pher = new MCrypt("rijndael-128", "ecb") // ECB, no IV

function encrypt(rawData, key) {
  pher.open(key)
  return pher.encrypt(rawData) // Buffer
}

function decrypt(encData, key) {
  pher.open(key)
  return pher.decrypt(encData) // Buffer
}
```

To code using [`cryptian`](https://github.com/tugrul/cryptian)

```
const {algorithm, mode} = require("cryptian")
const aes128 = new algorithm.Rijndael128()
const cipher = new mode.ecb.Cipher(aes128, null) // TypeError thrown: Value has got incorrect type. Should be Buffer or String.

function encrypt(rawData, key) {
  cipher.setKey(key)
  return cipher.encrypt(rawData)
}

function decrypt(encData, key) {
  cipher.setKey(key)
  return cipher.decrypt(encData)
}
```

How should I use `cryptian` with `ecb` mode without `IV` for `Rijndael128`?
I tried to search in examples but did not seem to find one.

Regards